# Maya C++ Creating Custom Material

Tags: maya-api

How in maya C++ do I create custom shaders/materials?

I also need to obviously also attach the shader code to this material.

I know how to access Materials with the API just creating seems difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own dependency graph node with mpxnode and create your own function to do you shader calculations. There are enough example shader codes in maya devkit. Here is the very basic lambert shader code from devkit. [You can take a look in this.](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2014/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/index.html?url=cpp_ref/lambert_shader_2lambert_shader_8cpp-example.html,topicNumber=cpp_ref_lambert_shader_2lambert_shader_8cpp_example_html258376d8-0e2e-4f2f-8bf1-cd066be4422a)

[Light Shader](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2014/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/index.html?url=cpp_ref/light_shader_2light_shader_8cpp-example.html,topicNumber=cpp_ref_light_shader_2light_shader_8cpp_example_html484f9c85-b376-4a8f-a08b-0664d63a7861)

And here is full list of [example codes](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2014/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/cpp_ref/examples.html)